# How changing object value of tuple is possible using copy by reference?

Tags: python

I am learning Python data structures. If Tuples are considered immutable, can anyone explain me how changing object value of tuple is possible using copy by reference?

```
>>> tuple1=[20,30,40]
>>> tuple2=tuple1
>>> print(tuple2)
[20, 30, 40]
>>> tuple2[1]=10
>>> print(tuple2)
[20, 10, 40]
>>> print(tuple1)
[20, 10, 40]
```

Comment: You have actually created lists, not tuples

Comment: You're using square brackets, which means you're not creating a tuple, you're creating a list. For a tuple, use parentheses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tuples are immutable in a sense that you can't change what objects are contained (i.e. the tuple itself remains unchanged). For example

```
>>> t = (1, 2)
>>> t[0] = 3
```

is not possible. However what you can do is *modify* objects that are referred to by tuples. For example:

```
t = (1, [2])
print(t)
t[1][0] = 3
print(t)
```

which outputs

```
(1, [2])
(1, [3])
```

The tuple `t` still contains the same objects as before however one of the objects (`t[1]`) has changed (leaving the tuple untouched).

Answer (score 3):

You have lists, not tuples. If you actually try this on a tuple

```
x = (1, 2, 3) # or x = tuple([1, 2, 3])
x[1] = 5
```

you get

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object does not support item assignment
```

which proves their immutability.

Also, more important, mutable/immutable and by-value/by-reference are two different things. The `x` variable is an actual reference to the actual object in memory (not a copy of its value), but still, the actual object cannot be changed. value/reference *would* make a difference on a mutable object though, since when you change it, you need to know whether you are changing the copy or the original.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the values by converting the *tuple* into a *list*, modifying the *list*, and then convert back to a *tuple*, your route is only working with a *list* version of the *tuple* if you look your final output is a *list*

```
tup = (20,30,40)
tup = [*tup]
tup[0] = 10
tup = tuple(tup)
```

> ```
> (20, 30, 40)
> [20, 30, 40]
> [10, 30, 40]
> (10, 30, 40)
> ```